# Disable showModal auto-focusing using HTML attributes

Tags: html, dialog, focus

As I am aware, the [`showModal()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#dom-dialog-showmodal) method runs the following steps which end up focusing elements within an HTML dialog (emphasis mine) :

> 1. Let *subject* be the dialog element on which the method was invoked.
> 2. If *subject* already has an open attribute, then throw an ["InvalidStateError"](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invalidstateerror)
>    [DOMException](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-DOMException).
> 3. If *subject* is not [connected](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#connected), then throw an
>    ["InvalidStateError"](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invalidstateerror)
>    [DOMException](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-DOMException)`.
> 4. Add an open attribute to subject, whose value is the empty string.
> 5. Set the dialog to the centered alignment mode.
> 6. Let *subject*'s [node document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-document) be
>    blocked by the modal
>    dialog *subject*.
> 7. If *subject*'s [node document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-document)'s [top
>    layer](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#top-layer) does not already
>    [contain](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#list-contain) *subject*, then
>    [add](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#top-layer-add) *subject* to
>    *subject*'s [node document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-document)'s [top
>    layer](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#top-layer).
> 8. **Run the [dialog focusing steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#dialog-focusing-steps) for *subject*.**

So the last step, `8`, will run the following [dialog focusing steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#dialog-focusing-steps) on the dialog. From my understanding (which could be completely wrong), these three steps from the dialog focusing-steps section of the spec specify that the element should only be focused if the element is not inert and is auto-focusable:

> 1. If subject is [inert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert), return.
> 2. Let control be the first descendant element of the subject, in [tree order](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order), that is not [inert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert) and has the autofocus attribute specified.
>
>    If there isn't one, then let control be the first non-inert descendant
>    element of *subject*, in tree order.
>
>    If there isn't one of those either, then let control be subject.
> 3. Run the [focusing steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusing-steps) for control.
>
>    ...

So, to me, it seems as though if my button below (see snippet) has the `inert` attribute or is not auto-focusable then it shouldn't get focused when the dialog opens. However, when I try and apply both attributes, it still ends up being focused.

---

Attempt with the [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) boolean attribute (which I thought would've made the dialog focusing steps *return* above, hence performing no focusing):

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");
document.querySelector("#open-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

document.querySelector("#close-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
#close-btn:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-btn">Open</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button id="close-btn" inert="inert">&times;</button>
</dialog>
```

Attempt with the [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) boolean attribute set to false (I believe this is how you set it to false, I also tried `autofocus="false"` which didn't work either):

**update 2023:** It appears the below hidden snippet using `inert` now does stop the button from being autofocused (when I asked this question it didn't, which I suspect was a chrome bug), however it stops the button from being clickable, so this isn't a valid option.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");
document.querySelector("#open-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

document.querySelector("#close-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
#close-btn:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-btn">Open</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button id="close-btn" autofocus="">&times;</button>
</dialog>
```

With both of these failing to work, I searched SO and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9152136/5648954) which suggested that I might also be able to use `tabindex="-1"`, which didn't work either.

I'm aware that I can blur the button once it is focused [using `.blur()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855683/11158354), but my question specifically is:

1. Why don't the two fiddles above disable the button from being automatically focused?
2. Is there an HTML attribute of some sort that I can use to stop my button from being focused?

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1929

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements cannot be focused on. You could add the `disabled` attribute to `close-btn`.

But, disabled elements cannot be clicked. Add the onclick attribute to `open-btn`. Set the `onclick` to this: `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('close-btn').disabled = false})`. This just enables the button 1 millisecond after the button is clicked. The timeout is required so that it does not enable `close-btn` before the dialog is opened.

If the dialog is re-opened, The button is automatically focused. We could add another onclick attribute to `close-btn`. Set `onclick` on `close.btn` to this: `this.disabled = true`. This disables `close-btn` when it is clicked.

Final result:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");
document.querySelector("#open-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

document.querySelector("#close-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
#close-btn:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-btn" onclick='setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("close-btn").disabled = false})'>Open</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button disabled id="close-btn" inert="inert" onclick='this.disabled = true'>&times;</button>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would work, it did to me

Being `selectorElement` the actual element we want to dont show the outline when is focused

```
selectorElement:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
}
```